# How to create a aliases for all the users linux..?

Tags: source

```
root@puppetclient-ubuntu:/home/azureuser#cat /etc/.bash_aliases
  alias extend_shutdown_15='bash extend_shutdown.sh 15 ; bash /bin/max_timetrack.sh'
  alias extend_shutdown_30='bash extend_shutdown.sh 30 ; bash /bin/max_timetrack.sh'
  alias extend_shutdown_60='bash extend_shutdown.sh 60 ; bash /bin/max_timetrack.sh'
```

#try to automate and execute the "source /etc/.bash_aliases" through shell script but it is not working means changes are not effecting.

```
root@puppetclient-ubuntu:/home/azureuser# cat alias.sh
#!/bin/bash
source  ~/.bash_aliases
```

when I do `source /etc/.bash_aliases` the alias custom commands are available only for root user and it is not available for all others expect "root"  if I do execute one time it should always available for the all users. Please help me to fix.Thanks.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: "VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"

Comment: Why are you sourcing it in `alias.sh` and not in .bashrc of the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, aliases are **temporary** and valid **only for the currently running shell**. When you run the `alias.sh` file, it executes **in its own shell**, not in the shell it was run from. So the script sources `~/.bash_aliases` (why this file and not `/etc/.bash_aliases`? I thought you want the latter?), but once the script ends, the shell also exits and whatever aliases could have been defined in the `~/.bash_aliases` file, they are gone.

That's the difference between **running** a shell script and **sourcing** it. If you run a shell script, it runs in it's own shell, so any changes to environment, aliases and the similar done in the script do not affect the parent shell (the shell the script was started from). But when you source the same script, it executes **in the current shell**, so all changes it makes stay after the script finishes (of course they stay as long as the shell lives - if you exit the shell, all changes are gone again).

Taking this into account, if you want aliases from the file `/etc/.bash_aliases` to be available to **any user** in **any shell they run**, the file must be sourced from `/etc/bash.bashrc` file. This file is executed whenever any shell (from any user) starts and is commonly used to set the initial environment.

So if you add the following line at the end of `/etc/bash.bashrc` (of course you must do it as root, to be able to edit the file):

```
source /etc/.bash_aliases
```

you should get what you want.

The `alias.sh` file isn't needed at all.

Comment: azureuser@puppetclient-ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/bash.bashrc 
source /etc/.bash_aliases 
automatically changes are not effecting in system but when I executed manually changes are effected  "source /etc/bash.bashrc "  but I don't want execute manually. Please help me..

Comment: @hariraj `/etc/bash.bashrc` should be executed automatically on shell startup, I don't know why it isn't. Probably your system is configured to execute some other file instead. You must find that file and insert `source /etc/.bash_aliases` into it. If you have a nonstandard system configuration, nobody can know which file is actually executing but you.

Answer (score 1):

**The standard approach** in Ubuntu is that aliases are defined and fully *controlled by the user*, not by the administrator. Yes, some default aliases are defined upon creation of the account, but these definitions are added to the private `.bashrc` file and thus can be deleted/changed if the user prefers so.

You can customize the default aliases that come with a new account by editing `/etc/skel/.bashrc`. That file is the default `.bashrc` file for new accounts.

**Control alias definitions as administrator**

If, instead, you wish to take control, as administrator, of the aliases of current users, you can define these in a script that you add in `/etc/profile.d`. All of the scripts present there are executed by `/etc/profile`, the systemwide `profile` script executed before the user's private `~/.profile` script for logon shells. Prefer this over directly editing `/etc/profile`, because the latter file is controlled by your package manager and may be overwritten during a future update.

Be aware that some users might not like you if you take such control. Also know that users can negate the aliases you impose to them with `unalias` commands in their private `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to put you alias.sh file in /etc/profile.d

in my case   /etc/profile.d/99-alias.sh it contains:

```
#Added by JP
alias du='du -h'
alias dfh='df -h | grep -v snap'
```

works for every login.

Comment: I have added same as you suggested but still not working 
"cat /etc/profile.d/alias.sh
alias extend_shutdown_15='bash extend_shutdown.sh 15;bash /bin/max_timetrack.sh'
alias extend_shutdown_30='bash extend_shutdown.sh 30;bash /bin/max_timetrack.sh'
alias extend_shutdown_60='bash extend_shutdown.sh 60;bash /bin/max_timetrack.sh'

Comment: automatically changes are not effected but when I execute manually  like "bash /etc/profile.d/alias.sh" changes are effected but I don't want to execute manually  ...

Comment: Please tell me what are you trying to achieve? Also, what does "alias" command shows after you put the file in /etc/profile.d

Comment: I have added the "alias.sh" file into "/etc/profile.d/" , so I want  aliases to be created for all the users in the linux system automatically. Now when I do the "alias" command in root user- there are no aliases created which I mentioned in alias.sh file.

Comment: Hello. how do you login to root user? what command do you use to test root user?